# jQuery's index method doesn't count right?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Example

```
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="four">0</li>  # again 0
  <li>1</li>  # again 1
</ul>

$("li").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

How can I get "4" when I click on the li with class "four"? By default it starts from 0 if in new parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML markup is invalid. You need to close the `li` by using `</li>` not `<li>`. After that, you will get `0` as expected:

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M3BPA/)**

If you want to get the index of the current clicked `li` element inside the DOM, you can use:

```
$("li").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).index('li'));
});
```

This will give you `4` if you click on the `li` with class `four`.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M3BPA/1/)**

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It does work :) & I changed it to </li> :)

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
var cache = $("li");

cache.click(function(){
  console.log(cache.index( $(this)));
});
```

Please read **[here](http://api.jquery.com/index/)** to know more about `.index()`

---

As per your new requirement you can do like,

```
$("li").click(function(){
 alert($(this).closest('ul').children('li').index($(this)));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/dd4He/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply using index() method will log the index number with it's parent ul lists and but if you use index('li') then it will log the index from all li lists. So, you can use like this:

```
$("li").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).index('li'));
});
```

but this will log index number from all document lists so add class to the lists you want to get index number from:

```
<ul class="myIndx">
  <li>0<li>
  <li>1<li>
  <li>2<li>
  <li>3<li>
</ul>
<ul class="myIndx">
  <li class="four">0<li>  # again 0
  <li>1<li>  # again 1
</ul>
```

then use like this:

```
$(".myIndx li").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).index('li'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By closing the `<li>` tags properly (with `</li>`), I get "0" when I click on four.

[See CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kjyFz)